# No sound after pulseaudio equalizer installed

Tags: 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa, ubuntu-mate

I've installed Pulseaudio-equalizer, then after reboot, my volume control was muted. Then i started to do a lot of mistakes. I've `sudo apt-get autoremove pulseaudio` so the volume control applet in the bar menu diseapeard. Then installed `sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer`.
Now i've installed again Pulseaudio but there is no sound anymore. My sound cards are well recognized: `cat /proc/asound/cards` :

> 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
>                         HDA Intel HDMI at 0xa321c000 irq 50
>
> 1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
>                         HDA Intel PCH at 0xa3218000 irq 51

I've made comeback the gnome-volume-control-applet by install `gnome-applets`. But my volume is allways muted and i can't uncheck mute.

Is there a way to reset the audio parameters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read this Ubuntu documentation page : [SoundTroubleshootingProcedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)

Then just have to `sudo rm -rf ~/.config/pulse/*` , my control volume unmuted instantly and the sound is comeback.